# Send Real time audio to bing Speech API

Tags: c#, naudio, bing-api

I am trying to use NAudio to receive the real time voice and send them in byte array to bing speech API.

I have used event handler to receive the audio and send to Bing Speech API. Below is the code I tried.

```
private void Source_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {   //convert the sound into a byte array

        writer.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
         memoryStream = new MemoryStream(e.Buffer);
        CallSpeechAPI(memoryStream);

    }
```

When I tried to execute, we were ended up with the below response.

Response:
OK
{"RecognitionStatus":"InitialSilenceTimeout","Offset":5000000,"Duration":0}
End Rec

When I tried to convert the exist .wav file to byte array and send them to API that works fine. But for the real time audio we are facing this issue.

Could some one please help what would be the issue and how to get it resolved.

Also if there is any option to receive real time audio as byte array, please let me know?

If there is any sample code , please share it with us.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We will support audio stream via byte array or io.stream very soon. Please stay tuned. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: The support for audio input stream is now available in the new Speech SDK v0.4.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/. You can find samples here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/Windows/csharp_samples/speech_recognition_samples.cs#L194.

Answer (score 0):

The support for audio input stream is now available in the [new Speech SDK v0.4.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/): . You can find samples [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/Windows/csharp_samples/speech_recognition_samples.cs#L194). You just need to implement your own AudioInputStream::Read() and ::GetFormat() according to the interface described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audioinputstream.read?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_CognitiveServices_Speech_AudioInputStream_Read_System_Byte___).

Thanks